# Which way is better for reconnecting to BLE device? Use `autoConnect=true` or perform repetitive scan?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

I have a BLE device which follows next forkflow: sleep until button (on device) is pressed -> Wake up and advertise for 60 seconds -> Wait until the phone ask for data -> send data -> close connection and sleep until next button click.

It mean that device do not maintain constant BLE connection. I need to reconnect to device when it's awake. I'm considering two different strategies:

1. Launch scan only for the first time. Save device mac address. Call `connectGatt` with `autoConnect` parameter equal `true`. Wait for auto connection if device disconnected.
2. Call `connectGatt` with `autoConnect` parameter equal `false`. `close` `BluetoothGatt` and start new scan just after device is disconnected.

I suppose, that the first approach is better in terms of power consumption. But I saw multiple suggestion to not use `autoConnect true`.

I have a bad feeling about second approach, because docs say "[Never scan on a loop, and set a time limit on your scan](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html#find)"/  Probably I should scan for 3 seconds, than wait for 30 seconds. But it looks like a loop.

Please advise me which strategy is better. Considering second approach, is it Ok, to scan all the time (with pauses)? Maybe there are some best practices to implement similar workflow?

Comment: So what did you end up doing?

Comment: @nexuzzz I ended up with the variant #1. I believe that google can optimize this workflow better that me and can invest more time/resources than me. Also this can be enhanced in future versions of Android without any work from my side.

Comment: @MyDogTom  did it work reliably?
How much time did it take to reconnect when phone wakes up?

Comment: @AshishPathak Sorry I haven't any information about this. We haven't tested precisely this scenario. Regarding the reliability. The application is not available for a large public, so I do not know how it behaves at scale.

Comment: Are you keeping a service in the background that performs the scan or is this only happening when an Activity is alive?

Comment: @AlejandroH.Cruz Unfortunately, I don't remember. I'm not working on that project anymore :(